# PyFirmata2 Arduino PermissionError(13, permission error) (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, arduino, pyfirmata

This is a auto coil maker using Arduino, I'm using PyFirmata2 to make it(I don't use C++ because C++ is kinda hard for me), then there are some error and I can't fix it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Knob\py.py", line 9, in <module>
    board = Arduino('COM4')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyfirmata2\__init__.py", line 13, in __init__
    super(Arduino, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyfirmata2\pyfirmata2.py", line 119, in __init__
    self.sp = serial.Serial(port, baudrate, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 33, in __init__
    super(Serial, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 64, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM4': PermissionError(13, '存取被拒。', None, 5)
```

(sorry if you notice I'm using Chinese)
I tried reboot my PC, run as Administrator and NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, also I run the code on other computer, still same error.Heres my code below:

```py
from pyfirmata2 import Arduino
import multiprocessing
import time
tmp = None
tmp2 = None
tmp3 = None
i = 0
port = 'COM4'
board = Arduino('COM4')
mycircle = float(input('How many circle you want?'))
carg = float(input('Coil arg?'))
rpm = float(input('Motor rpm?'))
print('start!')
def a0():
    board.digital[2].write(1)
    board.digital[3].write(0)
    board.digital[4].write(0)
    board.digital[5].write(0)
def a1():
    board.digital[2].write(0)
    board.digital[3].write(1)
    board.digital[4].write(0)
    board.digital[5].write(0)
def b0():
    board.digital[2].write(0)
    board.digital[3].write(0)
    board.digital[4].write(1)
    board.digital[5].write(0)
def b1():
    board.digital[2].write(0)
    board.digital[3].write(0)
    board.digital[4].write(0)
    board.digital[5].write(1)
def motor():
    global i
    print('start21')
    while True:
        for e in range(0,round(30/carg)):
            a0()
            time.sleep(tmp3)
            a1()
            time.sleep(tmp3)
            b0()
            time.sleep(tmp3)
            b1()
            time.sleep(tmp3)
            print(i)
            i = i+1
        e = 0
        for e in range(0,round(30/carg)):
            b1()
            time.sleep(tmp3)
            b0()
            time.sleep(tmp3)
            a1()
            time.sleep(tmp3)
            a0()
            time.sleep(tmp3)
            print(i)
            i = i+1
        e = 0
tmp = 60/rpm
tmp2 = 40*carg
tmp3 = tmp/tmp2
print(tmp3)
p=multiprocessing.Process(target=motor)
p.start()
board.digital[10].write(1)
while True:
    if i == mycircle:
        c = 1
        print('complate')
        p.terminate()
        board.digital[10].write(0)
        break
    else:
        pass
```

(I know it's kinda/very messy, because it's prototype)
System Info:Windows 10 Pro 2004 build 19041.1415, i7-8700, 8G ram, you can get other info by [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=Veriton%20M6660G)

Comment: I can't see any `board.exit()` in your code snippet, and a COM port requires exclusive access. Consequently, the `COM4` port could be considered open. Close all suspected apps, try in a fresh session (sign out -> sign in (or reboot in last instance)… Check steps in  [this guidance](https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2020/10/16/cant-open-device-com-access-is-denied-arduino-upload/).

Comment: Thank you @JosefZ , I will directly use safe mode next time and add board.exit() to my code, I can't test now because the computer is in my school now and today is Sunday in my country. If still not work I will use Linux to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is use Linux instead Windows. Windows have a lot of problem for me.
And Windows sux.